# Get Distinct values from List<T> in c#

Tags: c#, list, union

Hi Programmers!
                    Actually i need the distinct values from the List after adding some values to  List.
 My code goes like this

```
             List<Employee_Details> Temp = new List<Employee_Details>();
             Temp =(List<Employee_Details>) newform.Tag;
             EMP_DETAILS.Concat(Temp).Distinct();
```

But i directly ignore and do not add the values.

Please help me out.

Comment: var list = (List<Employee_Details>) newform.Tag; 
var distinct = list.Distinct()

//the list distinct contains distinct values

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Distinct` prefers both `GetHashCode` and `Equals` to be defined either for the type being compared, or to have an equality comparer supplied.  If two objects have the same hash code, then they are checked for equality.

You can implement `GetHashCode` and `Equals` for your type - but I sometimes find that a definition of equality in one case isn't always suitable for all cases - i.e. in UI cases it might be enough only to check that two objects' IDs match, because the UI might not have all the same data defined on the object that is actually available (therefore a single true equality can't always be satisfied).

So I prefer to implement the `IEqualityComparer<T>` type for `Employee_Details` and then supply an instance of it to the `Distinct` method

```
public class EmployeeDetailsComparer : IEqualityComparer<Employee_Details>
{
    #region IEqualityComparer<int> Members
    public bool Equals(Employee_Details x, Employee_Details y)
    {
        //define equality
      if(x == null)
      {
        return y == null;
      }
      else if(y == null) return false;
      //now check the fields that define equality - if it's a DB record,
      //most likely an ID field
      return x.ID == y.ID; //this is just A GUESS :)
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Employee_Details obj)
    {
        //define how to get a hashcode
        //most obvious would be to define it on the IDs, 
        //but if equality is defined across multiple fields
        //then one technique is to XOR (^) multiple hash codes together
        //null-check first
        if(obj == null) return 0;
        //now either:
        return obj.ID.GetHashCode();
        //or something like
        return obj.FirstName.GetHashCode() ^ obj.Surname.GetHashCode();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Now you can do:

```
EMP_DETAILS.Concat(Temp).Distinct(new EmployeeDetailsComparer());
```

Although note that **doesn't actually do anything** - you need to actually *capture* the return value of the `Concat` method, either as an `IEnumerable<Employee_Details>`, or 'realise' it into an array or list:

```
Employee_Details[] result = 
  EMP_DETAILS.Concat(Temp).Distinct(new EmployeeDetailsComparer()).ToArray();
```

Now you replace `EMP_DETAILS` with that.  If it's a `List<Employee_Details>` you can just do:

```
EMP_DETAILS = 
  EMP_DETAILS.Concat(Temp).Distinct(new EmployeeDetailsComparer()).ToList();
```

In reality implementing a good hashcode across multiple values is tricky - but the `^` approach works okay in most cases.  The goal is to ensure that you get different hashcodes for different `Employee_Details` instances.

Answer (score 2):

`Distinct` method uses `Equals` comparison of contained objects. If you have default implementation of Equals in `Employee_Details` then you probably compare references.

So you have to options:

1. Implement [Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.equals.aspx) method for your Employee_Details
2. Use overload of Distinct method that [accepts IEqualityComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx)

Comment: Not quite correct the Distinct method uses `GetHashCode` for equality, and if two objects have the same hashcode then it resorts to an `Equals` check.  So a decent implementation requires both to be defined, either on the type itself or via an `IEqualityComparer<T>`

Comment: Comparer has its own GetHashCode http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx

Comment: Yes - but decompile it and see what it does.  It just defers to `object.GetHashCode`, which for custom types is next to useless.

Comment: Default comparer - maybe, but if you implement it by yourself, can't you put there anything you want?..

Comment: Yes, sorry, you can - so you can define the `GetHashCode` method on the type itself, and that might well be suitable. As I say in my answer, though, sometimes defining general equality and hash codes type-wide doesn't always work in other situations.  Especially if that object is from the database and not all data is always loaded in all cases.  That's personally why I prefer a dedicated `IEqualityComparer<T>` for the job.  But, yes, if equality for a type can always be guaranteed to be able to be determined, then defining it on the type itself makes more sense.

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement [`IEqualityComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132038.aspx) in your class and provide your own `GetHashCode` and `Equals` methods.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132040.aspx

```
class Employee_Details : IEqualityComparer
{
    public int Employee_ID;

    public Employee_Details(int empID)
    {
        Employee_ID = empID;
    }

    public new bool Equals(object x, object y)
    {
        return x.ToString().Equals(y.ToString());
    }

    public int GetHashCode(object obj)
    {
        return obj.ToString().ToLower().GetHashCode();
    }

    public override String ToString()
    {
        return Employee_ID.ToString();
    }
}
```